# Is it valid to apply L'Hospital's rule rule to find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

Consider $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}$.

At first glance, it seems like the given limit is not in $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form. (It is $\frac{1^{\infty}-e}{0}$ form.) But I know that $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x} = e$, and therefore, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}$ is in $\frac{e-e}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$ form. In such a scenario, can I apply L'Hospital's rule to evaluate the limit?

I applied L'Hospital's rule and managed to evaluate the limit correctly, but I'm not sure whether it is valid to apply L'Hospital's rule here.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid?  What is your objection to applying L'Hospital?

Comment: You ultimately deduced that its of the required form. Yes its perfectly valid

Comment: Yes. That is indeed what the [statement of L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form) says, ie, the condition is that $\lim f=\lim g=0$ or $\pm\infty$ and that $\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm only taught to find the form by substituting the tending value of x (here 0) in the function. But when I do that I get $\frac{1^{\infty}-e}{0}$ form. So I was not sure about that.

Comment: So basically, you know the rule can validly compute $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ if $f(0)=g(0)=0$ (an some other conditions I won't spell out here also hold), but don't know if $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ is just as useful as $f(0)=0$. Well, replace $f(x)$ with$$f_{\operatorname{new}}(x):=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
f\left(x\right) & x\ne0\\
\lim_{x\to0}f\left(x\right) & x=0
\end{array}\right.,$$and it works just fine.